# What does this pipe angle mean?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I have this pipe and it says Weld 92.5 degrees Swept.

What does that angle mean, as in I don’t get how it’s 92.5 and what does swept and weld mean here too?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swept means the turn is extended over a greater distance to minimize clogging.

Weld means it is a fitting that is attached using a solvent based “adhesive” that literally melts the fitting and pipe surface such that they weld together

The fitting is a nominal 90 degree turn. The actual degree of turn in the sweep is 92.5  but don’t worry it is not a significant amount of variation and your 90 degree fitting will perform a 90 degree turn just fine

Comment: It's not 90 degrees precisely because it's a swept drainage fitting and you want to transition from vertical to slightly sloped towards the drain, NOT from vertical to Horizontal. Horizontal is BAD in drainage piping.